# CakePHP Multiple NOT Find's

Tags: sql, cakephp

I've got the below code which will not 'work'... How can I go about excluding multiple items from the SQL query? I've tried many different combinations without any luck :(

```
    $this->autoLayout = false; 
            $this->set('songs', $this->CcFile->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array(
                'track_title',
                'artist_name',
                'lptime',
                'id'
            ),
            'conditions' => array(
                'AND' => array(
                    'NOT' => array(
                        'artist_name' => 'Jam FM Bed',
                    ),  
                    'NOT' => array(
                        'artist_name' => 'Airtime Show Recorder',
                    ),
                    'NOT' => array(
                        'artist_name' => 'Jam FM Jingles',
                    ),  
                    'NOT' => array(
                        'artist_name' => 'Kent Scout Jingles',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'order' => array(
                'lptime' => 'desc nulls last',
                'artist_name' => 'asc'
            )
    )));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try that:

```
'NOT' => array(
    'artist_name' => array(
        'Jam FM Bed',
        'Airtime Show Recorder',
        // ...
    )
)
```

or

```
'artist_name NOT IN' => array(
    'Jam FM Bed',
    'Airtime Show Recorder',
    // ...
)
```

Comment: AFAIK: The IN is automatically added by CakePHP2.x if you use `'NOT' => array('fieldname' => $array)` - otherwise you have to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

---

**fixed code**

---

```
$this->autoLayout = false; 
        $this->set('songs', $this->CcFile->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array(
            'track_title',
            'artist_name',
            'lptime',
            'id'
        ),
        'conditions' => array(
                'NOT' => array(
                    'artist_name' => Array(
                          'Jam FM Bed',
                          'Airtime Show Recorder',
                          'Jam FM Jingles',
                          'Kent Scout Jingles')
                ),
        ),
        'order' => array(
            'lptime' => 'desc nulls last',
            'artist_name' => 'asc'
        )
)));
```

Comment: That doesnt work - it has the same basic PHP array key violation as the original code: never use an array key twice.

Comment: you can wrap your duplicate 'artist_name' entries in another array to avoid that - but the other answer is simpler to write, read and execute